# JQuery UI Autocomplete showing as bullets

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

The JQuery UI Demo page for autocomplete ([link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#default)) has a nice looking search box and drop down with nice colors and highlights and such.  When I implement it for myself, I end up with a bulleted list.  How do I get my drop down of suggestions to look like theirs?

A few notes/code fragments:

- I'm working in .NET land, so I'm using the `<asp:ScriptManager>` tag with `<asp:ScriptReference>`s inside it to get the hosted jquery.min.js (1.4.2) and jquery-ui.min.js (1.8.1) files from Google.
- My input box is fairly simple:
  `<div class='ui-widget'>
  <label for="terms">Term: </label>
  <input id="terms" class="ui-autocomplete-input">
  </div>`
- My autocomplete looks like: `$(""#terms"").autocomplete({source:""GetAttributesJSON.aspx"",minLength:2});`

I get the correct data back, so that's not the issue.  I just want fancy graphics.  Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you also linking to the jQuery UI CSS files?

Comment: @awshepard - build a theme, and include it: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ and problem solved. They appear as bullets because without the UI CSS they look like typical LIs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Karim79 and Zack has mentioned you need to style the list. You can create your own theme and download it. Further information can be found [here](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started#Visual_customization:_Designing_a_jQuery_UI_theme). Optionally you can use one of the many pre-built themes and include it in your document instead. Just head to the [Jquery Download Page](http://jqueryui.com/download) and select the theme you want.

Then just include the .css file

```
<link type="text/css" href="http://yourwebsite.com/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Aye there's the rub.  Thanks!

Comment: This worked well for me: <link href="~/lib/jqueryui/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />